# How to save List Of HashMap in android?

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap, save

I have a hashmap of string

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("name", name);
hashMap.put("number", number);
hashMap.put("profileImage", image);
```

and a List of Hashmap

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> recents = new ArrayList<>();
recents.add(hashMap);
```

Now I have to save this list

I have tried using https://github.com/pilgr/Paper to save this List

```
Paper.book().write("recents", recents);
```

but i can't get the list back

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = Paper.book().read("recents");
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = list.get(0);
String name = hashMap.get("name");
String number = hashMap.get("number");
String image = hashMap.get("profileImage");
```

Uses of the code

actually I'm passing this list to recycelerViewAdapeter and from there in OnBindViewHolder() I'm getting all the Hashmap values and displaying it to user

Saving Data Code

```
Paper.init(this);
List<HashMap<String, String>> recents = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("name", name);
hashMap.put("number", number);
hashMap.put("profileImage", image);
recents.add(hashMap);
Paper.book().write("recents", contacts);
```

Receiving Data Code

```
Paper.init(requireActivity());
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = Paper.book().read("recents");
Adapter = new Adapter(requireActivity(), list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Comment: I was able to save & retrieve the info from your code. So can you please elaborate on the issue? Do you get any errors? Do you get an empty list back? or anything else?

Comment: Sorry for that but this list returns me an empty list with null values in hashmap

Comment: Alright. So can you tell me from where are you getting the variables `name, number` etc?... During the save. Can you please post the code for that? If possible can you post the complete related class code? I want to make sure they're not null in the first place.

Comment: Can you please post complete code related to `Paper.book().write` where is it being done? I want to see if you're writing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson and SharedPreferences to do the same.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

Example:

```
private SharedPreferences sp;
private HashMap<String, Boolean> favs;
....
....
public void addFavourite(String wall_name) {
    favs = getFavourites();
    favs.put(wall_name, true);
    setFavourties();

}

public void removeFav(String wall_name) {
    favs = getFavourites();
    favs.put(wall_name, false);
    setFavourties();
}

private void setFavourties() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor pe = sp.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String j = gson.toJson(favs);
    pe.putString("Favourites", j);
    pe.apply();
}


public HashMap<String, Boolean> getFavourites() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String j = sp.getString("Favourites", null);
    if (j != null) {
        Type stringBooleanMap = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Boolean>>() {
        }.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(j, stringBooleanMap);
    } else {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```